# How can I use wso2am-analytics without Choreo?

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2am-4.1.0 and I want to use wso2am-analytics without Choreo (https://wso2.com/choreo/) and without connecting to the internet.

I just want to use it locally.

What should I do?

Is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with the introduction of API Manager 4.1.0, now we can leverage on-premise analytics using ELK stack. The WSO2 API Manager provides all the extension points and Kibana dashboards which can be deployed on an existing ELK stack.

Please refer:

- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/
- https://youtu.be/QCea3pvRCDA

Thanks!